# Loop through every IMG in current document

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, image

I'm making a Chrome extension and am wondering, what is the best method for looping through each IMG object on the current document using only JS/jQuery?

Comment: Depends. What do you want to do in the loop?

Comment: OK, for future readers, if you want to build some sort of collection. you probably want `.map()`. If you want speed, you probably want a `for` statement, or a native `forEach()`. If you want to run jQuery methods only, then you probably want jQuery's implicit iteration so you don't need to create a new jQuery object in each iteration. There are other possibilities too depending on what you want the loop to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$("img").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).prop("src"));
});
```

Logs every image's `src` in the console.

Answer (score 10):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( document.images, function( img ) {
    // ecmascript5 plz (but we accept a shim also)
});
```

Comment: +1 Since this is for a Chrome extension, a shim shouldn't be needed. Though I still think we need to know the specific use.

Comment: Psh, `[].forEach`. Also big warning, `document.images` is a live list. That means if you mutate the list in the `forEach` loop then your loop will start iterating more or less items or generally falling apart. I recommend `toArray(document.images).forEach(eachImage);`

Comment: @Raynos: `[]` access is slower :p but you're right about the good old HTMLCollection problem. That is seriously a thing you need to be aware of at least.

Comment: @jAndy - Such a micro-optimization -- the speed difference between one access of `[]` vs. one access of `Array.prototype.forEach.call` -- can't possibly matter. (You edited, so it became less clear what my "so what" applied to.)

Comment: @Raynos - You officially win this conversation.

Comment: @lwburk If one prefers the "terser slower" option vs the "faster more verbose" option then you end up writing jQuery code that looks like PERL rather then writing efficient, maintainable DOM code.

Comment: `var forEach = Function.prototype.call.bind( Array.prototype.forEach );` then `forEach( document.images, func... );`

Comment: @Raynos - Uh oh. Perl's been mentioned. This is like the programming equivalent of Godwin's Law.

Comment: @Raynos: It won't be all that destructive to use `forEach` on a live list, and it could be *more* destructive to make an non-live Array. What if one of the images is removed, and the code relies on `image.parentNode.something`. It will crash. But the `forEach` caches the `length`, so you'll never have an infinite loop situation, and it ignores `undefined` items in the loop, so you won't have any issue with holes.

Comment: ...worst thing would be that you add some images that end up in the middle of the list, and some original ones are ignored because their index is now at or beyond the original length.